# What does (&(&(&( .. ))) do in PowerShell (Windows)?

Tags: powershell, ldap, ldap-query

Specifically, for a script that updates a print server list on a domain:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter "(&(&(&(uncName=*)(objectCategory=printQueue))))"
```

This script was found at:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/f0ca6504-2643-4010-b53c-96696d7a401c/how-to-list-all-print-servers-in-a-domain?forum=winserverprint

Because this question involves special characters, I cannot easily search for this information.

Comment: `(&(condition1)(condition2))` is an `AND` condition for an LDAP filter. In your written example, you only need one `&` as the rest is overkill.

Answer (score 3):

In `(&)`, `&` is a `AND` logical operator in an LDAP filter. In similar fashion `|` is used as the `OR` logical operator. Since LDAP filters conditions are surrounded by parentheses, you end up with the syntax `(&(condition1)(condition2))`. Everything within the parentheses of `(&)` is part of the `AND`.

The LDAP filter syntax has nothing to do with PowerShell. PowerShell happens to support it with some of its commands.
See **[LDAP Filters](https://ldap.com/ldap-filters/).**

You do see it in PowerShell with the `ActiveDirectory` module commands. Some examples are:

```
# Find a user with first name John and mail domain of domain.com
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter '(&(GivenName=John)(Mail=*@domain.com))'

# Find users with first name John or last name John
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter '(|(GivenName=John)(sn=John))'

# Nested conditions: First name john with mail @domain.com OR simply just last name John
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter '(|(&(GivenName=John)(Mail=*@domain.com))(sn=John))'
```

---

In your example, there are two conditions that need to be present. So therefore you can use an `AND` operator. Only one `&` is needed though because no nesting is required for two conditions.

```
Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter "(&(uncName=*)(objectCategory=printQueue))"
```